# How to finish the async Future task before executing the next instruction Flutter

Tags: asynchronous, dart, flutter, dart-async

I make a function call to my database, which updates a local object after getting data and takes a few moments.

Because of the Async task, the program moves to the next line of code. unfortunately I need the local object that gets updated with the async call for the next line of code.

how can I wait for my async task to finish before the next piece of code is executed? thank you

edit: adding code to explain

```
updateUser() {
return FutureBuilder(
        future: updateUserData(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
            return Text("hello not");
          } else {
            return Text('Hello!');
          }
        },

);}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (_authStatus) {
      case AuthStatus.notSignedIn:
        return new LoginPage(
          auth: auth,
          CurrentUser: CurrentUser,
          onSignedIn: _signedIn,
        );
      case AuthStatus.signedIn:
        {
          updateUser(); //THIS TAKES A COUPLE SECONDS TO FINISH BUT I NEED TO SEND IT TO THE NEXT PAGE

            return new HomePage(
              auth: auth,
              CurrentUser: CurrentUser,
              onSignedOut: _signedOut,
            );
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: how to wait? use `await`

Comment: more on `await` [here](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/await-async#await-expressions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `await` keyword in `async` function.

eg:

```
  void someFunc() async {
    await someFutureFunction();
    // Your block of code
  }
```

Here your block of code wont run until someFutureFunction returns something.

Comment: clean and simple answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also use with custom async function like below example:

```
(() async {
   await restApis.getSearchedProducts(widget.sub_cats_id,widget.keyword).then((val) => setState(()
   {
      setState(() {
         data = val["data"];
      });
   }));
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, The below sample code has two functions, 
Below function is used to load the assets and return the JSON content.

```
Future<String> _loadCountriesAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/country_codes.json');
}
```

the other function will use the JSON content and convert the format to model and return to the class.

```
Future<List<CountryCode>> loadCountryCodes() async {
  String jsonString = await _loadCountriesAsset();
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
  // print(jsonResponse);

  CountriesCodeList countriesCodeList =
      new CountriesCodeList.fromJson(jsonResponse);
  // print("length " + countriesCodeList.codes.length.toString());
  return countriesCodeList.codes;
}
```

Usage in the class, defined a method to call the loadCountryCodes() function from services.dart file.

```
Future getCountryCodes() async {
var countryCodesList = await loadCountryCodes();

print("**** length " + countryCodesList.length.toString());
// Perform the operations, or update to the UI or server. It should be same for API call as well. 
}
```

Hope this helps.